# Who likes meat the best?

Tags: glitch-2011

I'm trying to get enough emblems for an idol (11). Since I have quite a pork factory at home, the easiest way for me to gain favour is with meat gifts. Is there a particular <strike>God</strike> Giant who will give me more favour in exchange for my meat or are they all the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, donations to giants are rated by how much the donation is worth, not any particular preference of any given giant.  The same donation will give you the same credit, regardless of where you donate it to.

I put together a system for determining how much a donation is worth, which can help you avoid going over the donation limits, called the [FavorSaver](http://agent86ix.github.com/glitch/).  I haven't played the game since they un-launched it, but the tool is based on their API calls, so it should still be current (assuming they haven't changed any of the formulas).

There's some help text in the tool itself that goes into some amount of detail about how the system works.  There's also [this thread on the forums](http://www.glitch.com/forum/general/9667/) which may be of use.